# Trie implementation compiles but crashes when entering data

Tags: c++, string, trie

I am using a trie implementation from topcoder.com and trying to store words in a trie structure. I used the code from the net. I can't seem to find out why my input is failing.

```
    #include<iostream>
#include<queue>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<map>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
#define M 10000
#define tr(c,i) for(typeof(c.begin()) i=c.begin(); i!=c.end(); ++i)

class Trie {
    public:
        int words;
        int prefixes;
        Trie* edges[26];
        Trie();
        void addWord(string word);
        int countWords(string word);
        int countPrefixes(string prefix);
};

Trie::Trie() {
    words = 0;
    prefixes = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<26;++i)
        edges[i] = NULL;
}

void Trie::addWord(string word) {
    if (word.size()==0) 
        words = words+1;
    else {
        prefixes = prefixes+1;
        char k = word[0];
        if (edges[k-'A']==NULL) {
            edges[k-'A'] = new Trie;
        }
        edges[k-'A']->addWord(word.substr(1));
    }
}

int Trie::countWords(string word) {
    if (word.size()==0)
        return words;
    else {
        char k = word[0];
        if (edges[k-'A']==NULL)
            return 0;
        else {
            return edges[k-'A']->countWords(word.substr(1));
        }
    }
}

int Trie::countPrefixes(string prefix) {
    if (prefix.size()==0)
        return prefixes;
    else {
        char k = prefix[0];
        if (edges[k-'A']==NULL)
            return 0;
        else {
            return edges[k-'A']->countPrefixes(prefix.substr(1));
        }
    }
}

int main() 
{
    int tests;
    cin>>tests;
    for(int t=1;t<=tests;t++)
    {
        Trie root;
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        string str[n];
        int ans=0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            cin>>str[i];
            root.addWord(str[i]);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            ans+=root.countPrefixes(str[i]);
        }
        cout<<ans;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any suggestions on what could be wrong? Thank you!

Comment: A *debugger* will make short-work of telling you *exactly* where the OS first noticed the wheels fell off your wagon. I'd start with that. And fyi, variable length arrays of non POD (plain old data) types are an accident waiting to happen. Most decent C++ compilers won't even *build* that.

Comment: `Trie* edges[26];` ? Really? Always 26? If no, I suggest to use `vector` instead of such array. And according to encapsulation move field to `privat:` section

Comment: ... or a `std::map<char,Trie>`

Comment: I am trying to implement this algorithm [link](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/using-tries/)

Comment: Remove all portions of the code which do not affect the crash. When you've found out which part exactly causes the crash, you will have a smaller yet still compilable piece of code which is easier to analyse. Post that one and tell us which line of the code makes the difference between crash and no crash.

Comment: Thanks a ton guys. My code was just accepting upper case letters, so i had to change that.